# How are Pointer Expressions in C are solved? Ex: ((4* (-(*p2)))/(*p1)+10 where *p1=12 ,*p2=4

Tags: c

I want to solve pointer problems.

The code was taken from book & I want to know how it was compiled

Ex: ((4* (-(*p2)))/(*p1)+10 where *p1=12 ,*p2=4

expected output is 9 but why?

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? A simple substitution will give you the correct result. That's basic math.

Comment: Just replace the (*p1) with 12 and (*p2) with 4, and you have (4*(-4))/12 + 10 = -1 + 10 = 9.

Comment: What does this have to do with pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute the values, the expression converts to

(4*(-(4)))/(12)+10

which is (Using BODMAS)

(-16/12) + 10

16/12 division is an integer division so you get -1+10 = 9

Comment: I do not think that the SO is the place to answer primary school math questions